# c# query com ciclos

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2013

Boas pessoal estou fazendo um trabalho em usando c# e os meus conhecimentos ainda são muito limitados e estou tendo uma duvida.
Eu tenho 2 tabelas e o que eu queria fazer era mostrar a informação das 2 em que a informaçao não se repetiria.

[image: Relação]

Isto é uma relação de 1-n em que 1 cabeçalho pode ter n linhas e o que eu queria era saber se existe alguma query sozinha que me consiga retornar exatamente o que eu quero sem repetir valores ou se tenho que usar várias querys
Vou mostrar o meu exemplo do código que tenho até agora.

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=HUGO-PC\HUGO;Initial Catalog=fatura;User ID=sa;Password=hugostoso07");
conn.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from my_cab", conn);
SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

while(reader.Read()){
    Console.WriteLine("Registo: {0}, Doc: {1}, Serie: {2}, Data: {3}, Ano: {4}, Terceiro: {5}, Processo: {6}, Requisição: {7}, NºDoc: {8}, Contribuinte: {9}, Nome: {10}, Morada_1: {11}, Morada_2: {12}, Localização: {13}, Codigo Postal: {14}, Desconto Cod Postal: {15}", reader.GetString(0), reader.GetString(1), reader.GetString(2), reader.GetDateTime(3), reader.GetDecimal(4), reader.GetString(5), reader.GetString(6), reader.GetString(7), reader.GetDecimal(8), reader.GetString(9), reader.GetString(10), reader.GetString(11), reader.GetString(12), reader.GetString(13), reader.GetString(14), reader.GetString(15));
}
reader.Close();
conn.Close();
if (Debugger.IsAttached)
{
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Resumindo o que eu queria que me mostrasse na consola era por exemplo

Cabeçalho nº1
 linhas nº1
 linha nº2
 linha nº etc

Cabeçalho nº2
 linha nº1
 linha nº2
 linha nºetc

É possivel fazer isto? Obrigado!

Comment: Tu sabes usar `joins`?

Comment: Não, nunca tive a necessidade nos meus projetos anteriores

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Olá, faça o seguinte :

```
 SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=HUGO-PC\HUGO;Initial Catalog=fatura;User ID=sa;Password=hugostoso07");
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT 
                                            my_cab.REGISTRO,
                                            my_cab.DOC,
                                            my_cab.SERIE,
                                            my_cab.DATA,
                                            my_cab.ANO,
                                            my_cab.TERCEIRO,
                                            my_cab.PROCESSO,
                                            my_cab.REQUISICAO,
                                            my_cab.N_DOC,
                                            my_cab.CONTRIBUINTE,
                                            my_cab.NOME,
                                            my_cab.MORADA_1,
                                            my_cab.MORADA_2,
                                            my_cab.LOCALIZACAO,
                                            my_cab.COD_POSTAL,
                                            my_cab.DESC_COD_POSTAL,
                                            mv_lin.ID_LINHA,
                                            mv_lin.T_DESC,
                                            mv_lin.ARTIGO,
                                            mv_lin.DESCRICAO,
                                            mv_lin.QNT,
                                            mv_lin.PRECO,
                                            mv_lin.DESCONTO,
                                            mv_lin.IVA,
                                            mv_lin.VALOR
                                        FROM my_cab
                                        INNER JOIN mv_lin
                                        ON my_cab.REGISTRO = mv_lin.REGISTRO", conn);

        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        string registroAnt = string.Empty;

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            if (registroAnt == string.Empty || registroAnt != reader["REGISTRO"].ToString())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Registo: {0}, Doc: {1}, Serie: {2}, Data: {3}, Ano: {4}, Terceiro: {5}, Processo: {6}, Requisição: {7}, NºDoc: {8}, Contribuinte: {9}, Nome: {10}, Morada_1: {11}, Morada_2: {12}, Localização: {13}, Codigo Postal: {14}, Desconto Cod Postal: {15}",
                                    reader["REGISTRO"],
                                    reader["DOC"],
                                    reader["SERIE"],
                                    reader["DATA"],
                                    reader["ANO"],
                                    reader["TERCEIRO"],
                                    reader["PROCESSO"],
                                    reader["REQUISICAO"],
                                    reader["N_DOC"],
                                    reader["CONTRIBUINTE"],
                                    reader["NOME"],
                                    reader["MORADA_1"],
                                    reader["MORADA_2"],
                                    reader["LOCALIZACAO"],
                                    reader["COD_POSTAL"],
                                    reader["DESC_COD_POSTAL"]);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("\t\t LOCALIZACAO: {0}, COD_POSTAL: {1}, DESC_COD_POSTAL: {2}, ID_LINHA,T_DESC: {3} , ARTIGO: {4}, DESCRICAO: {5}, QNT: {5}, PRECO: {6}, DESCONTO: {7}, IVA: {8}, VALOR: {9}",
                                reader["LOCALIZACAO"],
                                reader["COD_POSTAL"],
                                reader["DESC_COD_POSTAL"],
                                reader["ID_LINHA"],
                                reader["T_DESC"],
                                reader["ARTIGO"],
                                reader["DESCRICAO"],
                                reader["QNT"],
                                reader["PRECO"],
                                reader["DESCONTO"],
                                reader["IVA"],
                                reader["VALOR"]);


            registroAnt = reader["REGISTRO"].ToString();
        }

        reader.Close();
        conn.Close();

        if (Debugger.IsAttached)
        {
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

Comment: Muito Bom, era exatamente isso!

Answer (score 1):

Primeiro, sua dúvida não é com C#, é na linguagem de consulta ao banco de dados SQL, como você está usando SQL Server, T-SQL. Os comandos que você monta em C# são apenas ações para acessar o banco de dados, executar uma consulta (ou comando/ação) e depois para ler o resultado.

Segundo, seria bom estudar como escrever querys independente do aplicativo que você está usando, pois o impacto na aplicação é geralmente grande, principalmente quando a aplicação entra em manutenção e possui conjuntos de dados grandes.

Montar o SQL no código C# sem uma tratamento quando você precisa concatenar filtros provoca problemas de segurança, nesse caso você não faz isso, mas, é importante dar uma olhada em outros lugares. Uma leitura sobre o assunto (SQL Injection):
https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection

E terceiro, existem outras formas de realizar Joins, dependendo da estrutura de dados e de como as informações são armazenadas, esse conhecimento promove a você muita flexibilidade na hora de manipular as informações, uma referência retirada do W3S:

> Different SQL JOINs Before we continue with examples, we will list the
>   types of the different SQL JOINs you can use:
>
> INNER JOIN: Returns all rows when there is at least one match in BOTH
>   tables LEFT JOIN: Return all rows from the left table, and the matched
>   rows from the right table RIGHT JOIN: Return all rows from the right
>   table, and the matched rows from the left table FULL JOIN: Return all
>   rows when there is a match in ONE of the tables

E o link:
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

---

**Edit pelos comentários:**

Somente para os que não **clicam** no link acima, o primeiro exemplo desse link ensina a fazer um join que resolve o problema. Se você quer somente copiar a estrutura de um join sem saber mais nada, entre no link, copie e altere os nomes das colunas e tabelas, se você quer aprender o que pode ser feito com joins, leia o link que é bem básico.

Nas minhas experiências, quando tive de trabalhar com conjuntos de dados grandes, ou até mesmo em atividades rotineiras de análise de performance, eu tive de lidar com os bancos de dados. As vezes, evitar um join melhora as coisas, as vezes, não fazer um select sem um condicional melhora as coisas, mas, em todos os casos, eu precisava conhecer SQL e seu funcionamento para resolver meus problemas, seja num cluster ou nas aplicações de escopo isolado.

As pessoas cometem erros comuns só porque entregam do jeito mais fácil, acham que a culpa é do DBA porque a camada de dados fornece respostas lentas ou afirmam que o servidor não presta, esse é o pior. Mas, no final, e com o tanto de ferramentas ORM que estão sendo usadas agora, os conceitos simples do que não fazer resolvem o caso. Então, meu conselho é, Entenda o fluxo da sua aplicação para não fazer besteira.

Um post no site do Martin Fowler que achei interessante e que ilustra bem a importância de trabalhar sendo amigo do DBA (ta em inglês, digo logo):

http://martinfowler.com/articles/evodb.html#DbasCollaborateCloselyWithDevelopers

Até mesmo CI ou CD exigem um conhecimento de banco de dados que vai além de Joins. Se você já trabalhou em projetos com mais de 30 pessoas, sabe a dificuldade que da gerenciar esse tipo de coisa se seu processo de software e o conhecimento entre banco e aplicação não for equilibrado, os papeis tem que trabalhar juntos pra você não ter problemas.

Resumindo, não vou copiar um Join para facilitar a vida agora, quando posso te ensinar outras coisas que podem melhorar sua vida a longo prazo.

---

O post do @Luã Govinda Mendes Souza resolve de forma mais imediata, mas, você deveria procurar um conhecimento que traga uma "solução mais definitiva".

Comment: entendo que não é o caminho perfeito, entendo também que a escrita de comandos SQL é uma pratica ultrapassada. Porem creio que aqui na "stackoverflow" temos como objetivo propor soluções e na sua resposta apenas observei criticas. Favor proponha uma solução completa para a questão. Obrigado.

Comment: Desculpe, mas, não há uma resposta única com formato único e na minha visão esse tipo de resposta acaba limitando o aprendizado de quem responde e de quem pergunta. A começar pela pergunta associando um join a C#. Se ninguém explicar a ele que existem mais implicações do que copiar um join no que ele está fazendo, ele simplesmente pode copiar o código a coisa vai funcionar, mas, ele não aprendeu nada e o que você encara como críticas eu vejo como sugestões no estilo "Ensine a pescar".

Comment: Ok, entendo o seu ponto de vista, agora não vi a parte do "Ensina-me a pescar". 
Faça o seguinte. 
Poste uma responte melhor e "Ensine-o a pescar".Obrigado.

Comment: É porque você não clicou no link dos joins nem viu a citação do que se pode fazer com um join, ta bom, ta em inglês, mas, em TI as melhores referências são em inglês. o Tipo de join que ele queria fazer é o primeiro do link, com uma chave em duas tabelas do mesmo jeito. Justamente onde eu descrevo que existem outras formas de realizar joins, tem até a citação vei.

Comment: Fiz o edit, veja se agora ficou claro.